# Android Dalvik, supports general Java Swing, Awt, Swt, Gwt, SwingX, ApachePivot?

Tags: java, android, swing, swt, awt

For my Eee pad transformer, i am trying to write general Java code. But will it be same if i have Swing, Awt, Swt, Gwt, SwingX, Apache Pivot GUI's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no, your code won't be same if you have to swap Android GUI for AWT.

Long answer: abstracting away GUI is notoriously hard (just ask the Qt people). It can be done; as long as you plan for swapping the GUI layer early on, and maintain a good discipline of logic/UI separation (preferably on class/package boundaries), porting to a different GUI toolkit is possible. Painful, but possible.

Android does not support Swing, Awt or any of that - it has its own GUI layer. At least out of the box it does not, although I can theoretically envision an AWT implementation over the Android library. That said, cross-platform GUI libraries have to limit themselves to the lowest common denominator, and the end result looks ugly on all platforms (just ask the Qt people).

Comment: If i use Qt-Jambi. Will that be working in my CentOS desktop and Android Tablet?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Qt-Jambi hasn't been ported to Android so far.